# Did the British somehow imitate the Greek colonizers in India?

Tags: india, ancient-greece, british-empire

First of all I wonder whether the British headdress in India was somehow designed to resemble the headdress of the Indo-Greeks and Greco-Bactrians? For example, this is the image of Eucratides I, the Greco-Bactrian king minted on a coin (Indo-Greeks wore similar helms):

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/EucratidesStatere.jpg/220px-EucratidesStatere.jpg]

To me it bears resemblance to a typical British helm of the time:

[image]

I also read a point of view that the British monarch was declared emperor of India because the Indo-Greek kings called themselves "Basileos of India". I wonder whether it is true and whether there were other parallels?

Comment: More likely explanation is [convergent evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_evolution) in hat design.

Comment: Probably not consciously. But a hat with a wide brim is very useful in a hot climate, so it's little wonder both came up with it.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg still the natives of India and other warm countries such as Egypt, Kenya, Thailand did not wear such hats.

Comment: @Anixx: Good point. So what is your explanation? (Perhaps the natives were naturally acclimatized? Pigmentation and all that)

Comment: @Felix Goldberg no, they had different styles of headwear, quite popular being a turban.

Answer (score 10):

That particular helmet is of 20th century design - 19th century [pith helmets](http://www.nyc-techwriters.com/militaria/british_helmets2.htm) were initially modelled on the [Pickelhaube](http://i35.servimg.com/u/f35/12/75/00/21/z00211.jpg). No hellenic connection as far as I can see.

Comment: The WP page for [pith helmets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pith_helmet#Colonial_period:_the_Foreign_Service_helmet) has information on this.